# how to Update / delete the table records in ASPNETDB.MDF in single update / delete query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to know how to Update / delete the table records in ASPNETDB.MDF in single update / delete query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this article and I hope this will resolve your problem
[Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx)